# Bundle install fails when install unf_ext. "Cannot allocate memory error when installing unf_ext"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have this bug that happens on my remote server.

Though this isn't replicable in my local environment.

Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

Cannot allocate memory - /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1

```
Gem files will remain installed in /home/ubuntu/switch-web/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ubuntu/switch-web/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've checked the ram space for my  server and it's still pretty decent (2gb free).

Answer (score 6):

Pretty old question, but I can suggest an alternative answer. Instead of upgrading the server resources (and possibly costs), if the server does not have a swap partition you could temporarily create and enable a swap file:

Run as root:

```
# create a 512 Mb file
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1024 count=524288

# assign the correct permissions
chown root:root /swapfile1
chmod 0600 /swapfile1

# initialize the file as a swap file
mkswap /swapfile1

# enable swap
swapon /swapfile1
```

Once the build is complete, you can disable the swap file and delete it:

```
swapoff /swapfile1
rm /swapfile1
```

Comment: this is a life and money saver. thanks bro. Can I just leave it there though?

Comment: I guess you can, sure.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by upgrading my server, increasing the memory.